# What does this question on the application form mean?

Tags: vocabulary, questions

I am currently applying for an internship and this question is on the application form (I am not a native speaker):
*"What, if any, reasonable accommodations are necessary to perform the essential functions of the job? Please describe"*

What exactly do they mean? Are they referring it to the job description or to myself (because the following questions are kinda personal (drivers licence, first aid certified..)).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: These are generally called 'reasonable adjustments' in the UK. Asking for reasonable adjustments: from ACAS (the Advisory, Conciliation and Arbitration Service): _Anyone who's disabled and who needs a reasonable adjustment should talk with their manager or employer (or their potential employer if they're applying for a job). This is so: the person can explain their situation; the employer can understand how they can help; they can discuss and agree on reasonable adjustments together._ Clearly an applicant is free to start the discussion process simply by mentioning a disability.

Comment: This is the sort of form field that makes sense to answer for some, and has no context for others. It's like a field that asks for your spouse's ID number, but you have no spouse. You leave it blank or enter **N/A** for Not Applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reasonable accommodations" is a phrase taken out of the Americans with Disabilities Act, and used in other countries too. It refers to things that the employer might have to do differently in order to allow someone with a disability to do their job. For example:

- Installing ramps in a building to allow someone using a wheelchair to work there
- Providing audio screen readers to allow someone with difficulty seeing to do a job

The [meaning of accommodation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accommodation) here is:

> a special arrangement that is made for a person or group that has different needs to others

So the question is asking if you need the company to do anything special to do your job because you have a disability.

Comment: And if you don't know in detail, you can start the ball rolling at the application stage.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you!! :)

Comment: I have a disability (asthma) and disclosed it at application stage for a job in the UK Civil Service. I got the job and the reasonable adjustment was to not be required to answer the phone (talking for more than 5 minutes at a time was advised against by my doctor).